# Adobe Air to iOS Bluetooth connection with multiple devices

Tags: ios, air, bluetooth

Is there any AIR to iOS application, that connect to multiple iOS devices using Bluetooth (not peer-peer)? A single device must be able to connect multiple device. Is there any example or tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no support for this in Adobe AIR so you would have to rely on [native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html). The [AirNativeiOS-Bluetooth](https://github.com/jamieowen/AirNativeiOS-Bluetooth) extension seems to fit the bill.